# Excel cell stopwatch program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, timer

I have very limited programming experience (i.e. mainly VB in Microsoft Excel and a bit of Visual Studio) so looking for help on how to create a program which is in effect a timer.

I have a boolean cell in Excel (0 or 1) which changes throughout the day.  What I want to do is measure the time in a day for which this is 1.  What is the easiest way to do this?

I tried doing it in Excel but came across several issues such as constant refreshing needed as it wouldn't pick up when the cell value changed.  From years ago having used a bit of Visual Studio I thought this could be a good solution but struggling to understand how to get the cell value imported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please saw your work?

Comment: Haven't got anything to show you as don't know how to go about importing cell data.  I thought it would be pretty straightforward but clearly not (for me anyway).  Unless you want what I did in Excel which is very basic?

Comment: Did you wite any code behind the Excel? if yes then post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply handle the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Something along the following lines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngMyCell As Range
    Set rngMyCell = Me.Range("A1") ' or whatever cell you're monitoring

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngMyCell) Is Nothing Then
        If rngMyCell.Value = 1 Then
            ' Start Stopwatch if it's not running
        Else
            ' Pause Stopwatch if it's running
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```